# How to set mirrored for only one distribution in WSL2?

Tags: networking, wsl2, docker-for-windows

I would like to use mirrored network for my default WSL2 distribution, but for other distribution, I want them remain NAT. Especially for docker desktop, containers should have not had any impact to outer network, but now nginx of a container keeps attempting to bind 0.0.0.0:80, which has been already bound by IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is just not possible, at least not at the moment.  All WSL2 distributions run in the same  WSL2 Hyper-V virtual machine, so there's only one networking stack that is shared amongst all.  You'll notice that any change you make to an address/interface/route/etc. are shared across all running distributions.  This is the same for either NAT mode or Mirrored.

More information in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1731103/1210833), and, depending on your use-case, *perhaps* a potential workaround in [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1715457/1210833) using additional network namespaces.

Comment: Thank you. I will try hard to understand that workaround